# Converting asp.net 4.0 application with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I have an application which is in ASP.NET, ADO.NET, Oracle 11g

My structure of application is as follow

1. There are business entity classes for every entity in my application

   `Employee` entity contains

   ```
   a. Name
   b. Age 
   etc
   ```
2. I have written a stored procedure to fetch and insert every operation related to database using ADO.NET. It return `list<>` of Business Entities from by separate logic part.
3. Some of the presentation logic is split into `user-controls`.
4. Using `jquery-ajax` to load most of the component for `asynchronous load` on pages. To speed up the page.
5. Have used `data-caching` in my project.

Not wanted to move the project into `MVC 4` for better performance. Is it a good idea to move the project to ASP.NET MVC?

I also wanted to know weather it is technically ok to change it to mvc.

I don't want to change my database logic as it is well written.

So can I use MVC?

Any suggestion on any link provided will be a good help.

Comment: This is not an SO question, but you have put a lot of effort into helping others, I'd like to help if I can. 1) I love MVC but cannot promise you better performance from MVC over Web Forms. It's advantages are not so linear. 2) your JQuery-Ajax components will be at least as easy to perform once you have learned MVC well; Arguably better. 3) Data-Caching is fairly elegant in MVC. 4) I think EF would be a great fit for your List oriented design. You will find it an elegant time saver. --- I am feeding you my biases. I could recommend remaining with your current tool set or moving to newer.